# What is special about 008 for type juggling to fail?

Tags: php, type-conversion

What is special about the string '008' and anything *higher* that would cause the type juggling to (for lack of a better word) fail? All numbered strings below 008 work fine, anything from 008 or higher does not appear to ever equal a number?

To be more precise, it seems the comparison 007, 008 and 009 is where the issue lies, does PHP not count something like 008 as an integer?

```
$MyString='007'; //Works fine.
$MyString='008'; //Fails.
$MyString='009'; //Fails.

if($MyString==007) return 'ABC';
if($MyString==008) return 'DEF';
if($MyString==009) return 'GHI';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting a number with a leading 0 indicates octal (base 8).  Only digits 0-7 are valid for octal.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php